# Android NDK - How to get multiple events at one time from sensor queue?

Tags: android, android-ndk

How i can get 8 events from ASensorEventQueue_getEvents?

```
ASensorEvent eventBuffer[8];
    while (ssize_t numEvent = ASensorEventQueue_getEvents(accelerometerEventQueue, eventBuffer, 8) > 0) {
        event = eventBuffer[0];
        if (event.type == ASENSOR_TYPE_ACCELEROMETER) {
            LOGI("accl0(x,y,z,t): %f %f %f %lld",
                 event.acceleration.x, event.acceleration.y,
                 event.acceleration.z, event.timestamp);
        }

        //should return 1 to continue receiving callbacks, or 0 to unregister
        return 1;
    }
```

In this code ASensorEventQueue_getEvents returns me only one event.

if i do: `ASensorEventQueue_getEvents(accelerometerEventQueue, eventBuffer, 8) >= 8` my app crashs.